# Where can all the unity intellisense functions etc. be found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to get the intellisense autocompletion to work with Unity, but after a day of trying to make it work, no solution. Using C#

I'm not asking to solutions on this problem, but to ask where the documentation is found

Solution: @John 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

This has all the scripts/functions that intellisense gives you.

Comment: Do you mean that you're searching for the [Unity documentation pages](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)?

Comment: Yes, thanks I didn't realise it would have a simple name like 'Unity documentation pages'! Thanks for that, now I might be able to adventure into the C# realm on myself :D

Answer (score 1):

Check [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/using-visual-studio-tools-for-unity?view=vs-2017). You can find everthing there. For example, if you want to implement method from `MonoBehavoiur` use **Ctrl+Shift+M** or use **Ctrl + Space** with all suggestions.

Comment: Thanks.. This is more of an answer to how to fix intellisense, however I do not have any suggestions such as onTriggerPoint etc.

Comment: Because there isn't such a thing [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=onTriggerPoint+)

Comment: I was looking for the Unity documentation pages

Comment: Oh... It was that simple. Nevermind. Anyway, you can try this tools for more effective work :)